# Discord.py get server name or id by server link

Tags: discord, discord.py

So i want a bot that can return the server name/id by the join link.

Like:
`https://discord.gg/WxwgCQzW`

Will return:  `cryptoTribe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

### Better way

After some more digging, there's a better way to do this, using [`discord.Client.fetch_invite()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_invite), which returns a [`discord.Invite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#invite):

```py
async def get_invite_name(link: str):
    # Assuming bot or client is a global variable
    invite = await bot.fetch_invite(link)
    return invite.guild.name
```

### Old way

You can perform a GET request to the invite endpoint:

```
GET https://discordapp.com/api/invite/WxwgCQzW
```

Then, with the JSON data:

```
guild_name = data["guild"]["name"]
```

### Code

Using aiohttp:

```py
import aiohttp
import json

DISCORD_API_LINK = "https://discordapp.com/api/invite/"


async def get_invite_name(link: str) -> str:
    # Get the invite code of the link by splitting the link and getting the last element
    invite_code = link.split("/")[-1]
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(DISCORD_API_LINK + invite_code) as response:
            data = await response.text()
            json_data = json.loads(data)
            return json_data["guild"]["name"]
```