# How do I get the server name from the prompt string? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, disnake

There was a need to get the name of the server from the line with the invitation link, where this invitation actually leads. I get this line from the form. I use the disnake library (fork discord.py , therefore, I indicated it, because there are probably no differences in this regard). How can I actually do this and can I do it at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py get server name or id by server link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773324/discord-py-get-server-name-or-id-by-server-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `guild` property of an Invite to access the Guild and then get the Name from there.

Example:

```
invite = await bot.fetch_invite("discord.gg/example_invite")
print(invite.guild.name)
```

This was tested in discord.py but it should be the same in disnake.

Documentation: https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invite#disnake.Invite